# Filter same Value - Only take One - Without using CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, filter

I have the following table (which i get after a simple date filter Query)

now i want to Show the SalesAmount for the given Month, though i have Multiple values for the same ID in some cases, in which case, one Needs to be ignored and the other taken, otherwise (if there is only one entry for the ID, that value should be taken)

```
| TableID |SalesOpportunityID| OrderID | SalesCycleStatus | Status | SalesAmount | OrderIncMonth |
|    1    |   14551          |  NULL   |     Oppurtunity  |  Lost  |    1556,316 |     2013-10   |
|    2    |   12551          |  14515  |       Order      | Active |   23563,23  |     2013-10   |
|    3    |   12151          |  15131  |       Order      | Active |  2212352,43 |     2013-10   |
|    4    |   14531          |  NULL   |     Opportunity  |  Lost  | 32152332,1  |     2013-10   |

|    5    |   12651          |  NULL   |     Opportunity  |  Won   |   23525,3245|     2013-10   |
|    6    |   12651          |  21452  |       Order      | Active |   23525,3245|     2013-10   |
```

As you can See, TableID = 5 and = 6 are basicaly the same Order,

just stored as a Sales Opurtunity, than (after it was won) turned into an Order and Stored again,
since i am trying to Calculate the Summ of all Oportunities and Orders for the Month being,

i Need to filter out these Double Values, and do so by: Taking only the Value for the SalesOpportunityID where the SalesCycleStatus is = Order

(IF of curse there are 2 entries with the same SalesOpportunityID, Otherwise take SalesAmount for SalesOpportunityID - regardles weather the SalesCycleStatus is an Order or an Opportunity)

Is there a way to do this without using CTE ?
thanks a lot for your Help :) !

Comment: Why don't you want to use a CTE? Are you against using ROW_NUMBER() as well?

Comment: no not really against ROW_NUMBER()
CTE is just so problematic, because you can't really use it with other code or join it, and i didn't want to use a UNION

Comment: *you can't really use it with other code or join it* - You certainly can, it is no different to a subquery if you are not using it recursively. I suspect you are not using them properly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also achieve this using `ROW_NUNBER()` which could be more efficient as it only requires one table scan:

```
SELECT  TableID, 
        SalesOpportunityID, 
        OrderID, 
        SalesCycleStatus, 
        Status, 
        SalesAmount
FROM (  SELECT  TableID, 
                SalesOpportunityID, 
                OrderID, 
                SalesCycleStatus, 
                Status, 
                SalesAmount ,
                RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY SalesOpportunityID 
                                                ORDER BY CASE WHEN SalesCycleStatus = 'Order' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, TableID)
        FROM    T
    ) t
WHERE t.RowNumber = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, helped me,
Only that I had to rewrite RowNumber like this:

RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY SalesOpportunityID  ORDER BY CASE WHEN SalesCycleStatus = 'Opportunity' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, TableID)

Comment: Sorry, my Bad, it should have been `CASE WHEN SalesCycleStatus = 'Order' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END`, but if your only two possible statuses are opportunity and order then it doesn't matter either way.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to do this:  the first one I'd suggest would be a subquery using `NOT EXISTS` as follows:

```
SELECT TableID, SalesOpportunityID, OrderID, SalesCycleStatus, Status, SalesAmount 
FROM TestTable 
WHERE 
  SalesCycleStatus = 'Order' OR
  NOT EXISTS
    (
      SELECT TableID 
      FROM TestTable sub 
      WHERE 
        SalesCycleStatus = 'Order' AND
        sub.SalesOpportunityID = TestTable.SalesOpportunityID
    )
```

Click here for the full [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5e450/2) example